# Transpose rows data into columns in MYSQL

Tags: phpmyadmin

[image: Please help me with the scrip that can change table1 into table2 given in the post. I wish to change the rows data into columns]

Please help me with the scrip that can change table1 into table2 given in the post. I wish to change the rows data into columns

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is a pivot table. There isn't really any quick and easy way to do this in MySQL (as far I know).

I'm much more familar with T-SQL, but I'm going to give it a try. One caveat, is that I would have to process your grades into decimal values (for a percentage) in order to use the `AVG` function. I'm not doing that in this example, as you may have a table to join to that does that for you.

I'm referencing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7675121/2781687) from StackOverflow and [this solution](https://codingsight.com/pivot-tables-in-mysql/) from codingSight.

```sql
SELECT
      `regno`,
      AVG(IF(`subject` = 'mathematics', `grade`, NULL)) AS `mathematics`,
      AVG(IF(`subject` = 'english language', `grade`, NULL)) AS `english language`,
      AVG(IF(`subject` = 'economics', `grade`, NULL)) AS `economics`,
      AVG(IF(`subject` = 'government', `grade`, NULL)) AS `government`,
      AVG(IF(`subject` = 'biology', `grade`, NULL)) AS `biology`,
      AVG(IF(`subject` = 'chemistry', `grade`, NULL)) AS `chemistry`,
      AVG(IF(`subject` = 'physics', `grade`, NULL)) AS `physics`
FROM results
GROUP BY `regno`;
```

I hope this helps!

*EDIT: I overlooked just using the `MAX` or `MIN` functions (instead of `AVG`). If you don't have multiple grades for the same student you can use the code below:*

```
SELECT
      `regno`,
      MAX(IF(`subject` = 'mathematics', `grade`, NULL)) AS `mathematics`,
      MAX(IF(`subject` = 'english language', `grade`, NULL)) AS `english language`,
      MAX(IF(`subject` = 'economics', `grade`, NULL)) AS `economics`,
      MAX(IF(`subject` = 'government', `grade`, NULL)) AS `government`,
      MAX(IF(`subject` = 'biology', `grade`, NULL)) AS `biology`,
      MAX(IF(`subject` = 'chemistry', `grade`, NULL)) AS `chemistry`,
      MAX(IF(`subject` = 'physics', `grade`, NULL)) AS `physics`
FROM results
GROUP BY `regno`;
```

Comment: with your code you have to always know the classes thtát exist and you have ti adept it ocaasionally, my solution for pivot ables is flexible and doesn't need any adaption

Comment: I'm most grateful, the query has worked perfectly. God bless you.

Comment: @nbk, agreed. I went with a simple answer that’s easy to understand.

Comment: @EmmanuelT.I. - You’re welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Please provide Data as Text, your image, is for an ocr not really good enough

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1 (
>   `regno` VARCHAR(6),
>   `subject` VARCHAR(16),
>   `grade` VARCHAR(2)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO table1
>   (`regno`, `subject`, `grade`)
> VALUES
>   ('7007gd', 'mathematics', 'C6'),
>   ('7007gd', 'english language', 'CS'),
>   ('7007gd', 'economics', 'C5'),
>   ('7007gd', 'government', '83'),
>   ('7007gd', 'biology', 'C6'),
>   ('7010gd', 'mathematics', 'C6'),
>   ('7010gd', 'english language', 'C5'),
>   ('7010gd', 'economics', 'C5'),
>   ('7010gd', 'government', 'C5'),
>   ('7010gd', 'biology', 'C5'),
>   ('70151f', 'mathematics', 'C6'),
>   ('70151f', 'english language', 'C5'),
>   ('70151f', 'economics', 'C6'),
>   ('70151f', 'government', 'C5'),
>   ('70151f', 'biology', 'C5'),
>   ('70151f', 'chemistry', 'C5'),
>   ('70151f', 'physics', '83');
> ```

> ```
> SET @sql = NULL;
> SELECT
>   GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
>                CONCAT('MAX(IF(`subject` = "', `subject`,'", `grade`,"")) AS "',`subject`,'"')
>               ) INTO @sql
> FROM table1;
>
>
> SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT  `regno`,  ', @sql, ' 
>                   FROM table1 s
>                  GROUP BY s.`regno`
>                  ORDER BY s.`regno`');
> #SELECT @sql;
> PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
> EXECUTE stmt;
> DEALLOCATE stmt;
> ```
>
> ```
> regno  | biology | chemistry | economics | english language | government | mathematics | physics
> :----- | :------ | :-------- | :-------- | :--------------- | :--------- | :---------- | :------
> 7007gd | C6      |           | C5        | CS               | 83         | C6          |        
> 7010gd | C5      |           | C5        | C5               | C5         | C6          |        
> 70151f | C5      | C5        | C6        | C5               | C5         | C6          | 83
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=34fcfeff5d26a55259a4cd6b656fb39c)*

Comment: note that group_concat has a string limit to 1025. I am not sure if this can be set to more...

Comment: you can increase it https://stackoverflow.com/a/29600336/5193536